# How to export all layers as a separate sequences in Krita?

Tags: krita

I was hoping someone could please offer some help with Krita?

I know how to export all layers separately as a single image, but I cannot export all layers separately as a sequence?

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I have more than 30 layers, but the "Export Layers" button only exports on image from each layer and the "Render Animation" button merges them all into one file sequence. Instead, I want 30 file sequences of all the layers..

Thanks,
Shaun